# Rewrite rule or server snippet in Nginx ingress with query parameter

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a cluster with Nginx ingress. I receive an API request, for example:

```
/api/v1/user?json={query}
```

I want to redirect this request with ingress to my service. I want to modify it like this:

```
/api/v2/user/{query}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your domain name is `example.com,` and you have a service called `example-service` exposing port `80`, you can achieve this task by defining the following ingress rule.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
       if ($arg_json) {
           return 302 https://example.com/api/v2/user/$arg_json;
       }
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
  name: ingress-rule
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/v1/user(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know if it is ok.

Comment: Worth to mention that [snippet vulnerability](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7837) should be taken into account.

Comment: Just want to call out that the "arg_json" is the nginx convention for query parameters where the query parameter name is `json`.  If I wanted to capture `?foo=bar` my if statement would look like `if ($arg_foo = "bar")`.  Not sure why that isn't better documented!